# p-groups realisable as 1+J,where J is a nilpotent finite F-Algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory

There is a functor F:   {finite nilpotent Algebra over a finite field F}  -> {finite p-groups}
sending J to 1+J.(You can think of J as the Jacobsonradical of 1F+J) and sending f:A->B to F(f):1+A -> 1+B with F(f)(1+a)=1+f(b).
I want to know which classes of p-groups are realisable as 1+J and maybe if you see some interesting properties of the functor F.
For example if J^2 = 0,then G=1+J is elementary abelian and if J^3=0 then G=1+J is special.
Such realisations could be interesting since,we have for example in general G' $\leq $ 1+J^2 and a series 1+J $\leq$ 1+J^2 ... $\leq$ 1+J^k =0 and there it is known that the characters of 1+J are induced from linear characters of a subgroup 1+A where A is a subalgebra of J.

Comment: These groups are sometimes called algebra groups - this might help your search.  There's a great deal of literature on their character theory.

Comment: thank you.do you know a paper which contains most of the known results about those groups?by the way: if someone has an interesting example of a p-group not realisable as 1+J,I would be glad if you post it.


Answer (score 2):

For algebras over non-prime fields, a good reference is Isaacs (1995).  It proves a fundamental theorem establishing that these F-algebra groups behave like |F|-groups, not just like *p*-groups, for char(F) = *p*.  I think these groups have been studied over **Z**/*p***Z** or even **Z**/*p*<sup>*n*</sup>**Z** for a very long time.

As far as a *p*-group not of the form 1 + *J*: any cyclic *p*-group of large enough exponent will do.  For instance, the cyclic group of order 8 is not of the form 1 + *J*: |*P*| = |*J*|, and so *J* has dimension 3 over *F* = **Z**/2**Z**.  Hence 1F+1J has dimension 4, and *P* is contained in a Sylow 2-subgroup of GL(4,2), and hence has exponent dividing 4.  Similar bounds hold for odd *p*: the cyclic group of order *p*<sup>2</sup> is not an algebra group, for instance.  Every group of order dividing 8 (other than the cyclic group of order 8) is an algebra group.

I assume you have already seen the use of *p*-restricted Lie algebras in finite *p*-groups.  This takes a *p*-group and associates a Lie algebra with pretty similar properties as *J* has in 1+*J*.  If not, then this may be exactly what you are looking for and is very well studied (refs on requests, but any "good book on *p*-groups" should work).

- Isaacs, I. M.
  Characters of groups associated with finite algebras. 
  J. Algebra 177 (1995), no. 3, 708–730.
  MR[1358482](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1358482)
  DOI:[10.1006/jabr.1995.1325](http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jabr.1995.1325)

Comment: The groups of order 16 that are not algebra groups are exactly the cyclic, the maximal class (D16, QD16, Q16), and the modular group.  The groups of order p^3 (p odd) that are not algebra groups are the cyclic and the extra-special group of exponent p^2.  I am nervous about p^4: it seems (too) rare to be an algebra group.